# Application Insights - Scheduled Analytics

Tags: azure-application-insights

Where did the scheduled analytics go in Azure portal? I had production alerts configured in with this and it suddenly disappeared as an option. I have no idea if the alert is still monitoring the services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monitors are still running. You can still access them turning this feature on using the following URL https://portal.azure.com/?feature.scheduledanalytics=true.

Note, Scheduled Analytics is in private preview and hence not recommended for live-site monitoring; as it’s a preview functionality not backed by SLA. We strongly recommend to migrate to Log Alerts for Application Insights instead which is General Availability with SLA and recommended for production use; with similar functionality (i.e.) monitoring using periodic Analytics query execution.

Log Alerts: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/log-alerts-for-application-insights-general-availability/